# Do we have priority queue which supports delete operation with same complexity as other operations?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

Priority Queue is famous for retrieving max or min element from a set. 
The two common operations on priority queue are **Insert** and **DeleteMin/DeleteMax**.
Do we have priority queue which supports **Delete(x)** ?
The meaning of **Delete(x)** is two **delete the item x from priority queue**.

The naive way to do this is to find item x and delete it, but it will take linear time. I am looking for some better algorithm.

Comment: You can delete from a Fibonacci heap in O(log N).

Answer (score 6):

Some types of priority queues do support this operation. Typically, you would do this by having the **delete**(x) operation accept x as a pointer inside the data structure indicating which element should be deleted. For example, in a binomial heap or Fibonacci heap, where each element is stored as a node in a forest, the **insert(x)** operation might hand back a pointer to the node that holds element x, and **delete**(x) can then follow the provided pointer to quickly locate the element to delete.

In most priority queues that support **delete**(x) this way (Fibonacci heap, binomial heap, pairing heap, etc.), the complexity of **delete**(x) is the same as the complexity for **delete-min**, but this depends on the particular implementation of the data structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it was helpful .... but most of the time user may not know the pointer of the element, any suggestions how to deal in that case?

Comment: @rgaut You can always do something like this internally inside the priority queue. Store a hash table mapping from elements to their "positions" in the queue (for some definition of "position") and keep that hash table in sync with the rest of the data structure. You can then implement **delete**(x) by looking up x in the hash table and proceeding from there to find the element to delete.

Comment: Thanks, yes keeping a hash-table makes sense.

Comment: You can also use this scheme to overwrite the thing in the priority queue with "tombstone that sorts like the thing you deleted," and modify extract-min to skip over tombstones.  This is amenable to amortised analysis---you get the desired time bound for any sequence of operations beginning with an empty queue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cheat way which I use if the Priority Queue library does not support `Delete(x)` functions.

I will use 2 priority queues, `ORI` and `DELETED`.
`ORI` would be my original priority queue, and `DELETED` serves as a pool to flag which elements are deleted.

To add an element, simply add it into `ORI`.
To remove an element, simply add it to `DELETED`.

The magic comes when you query for the top (Eg Min/Max) of the priority queue:

1) **While** the top of `ORI` is equal to `DELETED`, delete the top of both priority queues (using DeleteMin/DeleteMax)

2) Once the top of both priority queues are not equal, the top of `ORI` would be the actual 'top' you are looking for.

This is somewhat delaying the 'deletion' until the element to be deleted is at the top of the priority queue. This works because if an element is flagged to be deleted is not the top of the priority queue, the top of the priority queue won't change.

However the downsides to this 'cheat' is that more memory is required to store the elements flagged for 'deletion'.

The complexity for the deletion function ends up to be armotized O(log N)

Edit: 
This way, you won't have to implement your own data structures :P
I have been using this technique in programming competitions in C++ using STL Priority Queues.

Comment: An interesting idea, but it makes `Peek()` an O(log n) operation, when normally it's an O(1) operation.

Comment: It kind of is O(1) armotized as the O(log N) can be attributed to the delete. (Eg you can repeatedly call Peek() consecutively and no further deletions will happen -> O(1))

Comment: the real deletion work can also be moved into the insertion, thus guaranteeing O(1) `Peek()`

Answer (score 1):

Any balanced binary tree structure can store a sorted sequence under inserts and deletes, not just of the minimum element, and one gets similar asymptotic time bounds to binary heaps.